# Micromamba and Dockerfile error: /bin/bash: activate: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile, conda

Used to have a Dockerfile with `conda` and `flask` that worked locally but after installing `pytorch` had to switch to `micromamba`, the old `CMD` no longer works after switching to image `mambaorg/micromamba:1-focal-cuda-11.7.1`, this is how my Dockerfile looks like right now:

```
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1-focal-cuda-11.7.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY environment.yml .

RUN micromamba env create --file environment.yml

EXPOSE 5001

COPY app.py .

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate env-app && flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5001"]
```

Now I get error:

`/bin/bash: activate: No such file or directory`

but before when I was using `conda` it was working, I think the CMD command needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming these 2 files:

#### environment.yml

```yaml
name: testenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python >= 3.9
  - flask
```

#### app.py

```py
from flask import Flask

# Create a Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


# Define a route for the root URL
@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Run the Flask app on the local development server
    app.run()
```

---

Then in your Dockerfile you don't activate the environmnent but use the path to environment, e.g. `/opt/conda/envs/testenv/bin/flask` (note the `testenv` in the path and in the `environment.yaml`):

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM mambaorg/micromamba:1-focal-cuda-11.7.1

WORKDIR /app

COPY environment.yml .

RUN micromamba env create --file environment.yml

EXPOSE 5001

COPY app.py .

CMD micromamba run -n testenv flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5001
```

---

To build:

```
docker build . -f Dockerfile -t my/image:name
```

To run:

```
docker run --rm -i -t -p 5001:5001 my/image:name
```

Then navigating the browser to `localhost:5001` you should see `Hello World`.

Comment: thanks so much :) this worked I just changed: `CMD /opt/conda/envs/{MY_ENV}/bin/flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5001`; I thought CMD always needed to be followed by quotes such as `CMD "some commands"` or the array as in `CMD ["my", "command"]`

Comment: I wouldn't circumvent the activation like this - it's fine for your trivial example, but packages that have activation scripts will fail in hard to diagnose ways. One would be fine with: `CMD micromamba run -n testenv flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5001`

Comment: @merv good point, I've edited my answer.